# How do I hide/show DIV element in Razor views?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

Im trying to complete this very simple task using razor engine (c#+html). Im editing the cshtml file of this view and essentially im trying to achieve this exact code but in "razor" format. Here is what im trying to achieve but in javascript:

HTML:

```
<p>How many check boxes do you want when clicked on a radio button?</p>
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igotnone" onclick="show1();" />
None
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igottwo" onclick="show2();" />
Two
<div id="div1" class="hide">
  <hr><p>Okay Cool! Here are those two...</p>
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="one">
One &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="two">
Two
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function show1(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='none';
}
function show2(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}
```

What is the code for achieving this exact effect but in cshtml/whatever else is necessary in razor engine?

Total newb when it comes to this front end stuff so I have a second follow up question. I am led to believe that this function needs to go elsewhere like in the "controller" files. Is that necessary or can I insert this method into my cshtml file? Because currently I am editing the already published website through Microsoft Azure's "App preview editor" and it doesn't seem that I can get access to the solution with those files (unless there is o.o)

Thanks!

Comment: Razor is server side code. Javascript is client side code. If you want to handle client side events then you need javascript (as you already have)

Comment: I guess the next question is then where would this go in my directory to have the page execute the above code? NVM Got it THANKS!!!!